# shuffle an array with a "limit" in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

**What I try to achieve:** randomize the order of all elements in an array, but allow each element to change its position only by a limited number of "steps".

Say I have an array like below, and I wish to randomize with a limit of **2 steps**:

```
$array = [92,12,2,18,17,88,56];
```

An outcome could be: `[2,12,92,17,18,56,88]` (all elements of the array moved a maximum of 2 steps), but it could not be: `[56,92,2,12,17,18,88]` because in this example `56` moved too far.

I considered using a combination of [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and [shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle), but this is problematic because elements will be shuffled inside their chunk, resulting in elements at the beginning or end of a chunk only moving in one direction. This is what I came up with (and problematic):

```
// in chunks of 3 an element can move a max. of 2 steps.
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 3); 
$newChunks = [];

foreach ($chunks as $chunk){
    $keys = array_keys($chunk);
    shuffle($keys);

    $newChunk = [];
    foreach ($keys as $key){
        $newChunk[$key] = $chunk[$key];
    }

    $newChunks[] = $newChunk;
}
```

Another idea I had was to get the key of the item in the array and with [rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) add of subtract my limit. For example:

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    $newArray[] = ["key" => $key+rand(-2,2), "value" => $value];
};
```

This creates a new array with each of its elements being an array with the  original value plus a value `key` that is the original key plus or minus 2. I could flatten this array, but the problem with this is that I can have duplicate keys.

Comment: Why not write some code to achieve this? Looks like a pretty good exercise to learn TDD

Comment: @NicoHaase, I understand what you are saying. My problem is thinking of a solution and not so much writing code. Meaning I cannot write code that works without having come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution in one pass :

Try to swap each element at position `i` with an element between `i` (stay in place) and `i+x`. I look only forward to avoid swaping an element several times. And I need an extra array to flag the already swapped elements. I don't need to process them in the future as they were already moved.

```
function shuffle_array($a, $limit)
{
    $result = $a ;
    $shuffled_index = array() ; // list of already shuffled elements

    $n = count($result);
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $n ; ++$i)
    {
        if( in_array($i, $shuffled_index) ) continue ; // already shuffled, go to the next elements

        $possibleIndex = array_diff( range($i, min($i + $limit, $n-1)), $shuffled_index) ; // get all the possible "jumps", minus the already- shuffled index
        $selectedIndex = $possibleIndex[ array_rand($possibleIndex) ]; // randomly choose one of the possible index

        // swap the two elements
        $tmp = $result[$i] ;
        $result[$i] = $result[$selectedIndex] ;
        $result[$selectedIndex] = $tmp ;

        // element at position $selectedIndex is already shuffled, it needs no more processing
        $shuffled_index[] = $selectedIndex ; 
    }

    return $result ;
}

$array = [92,12,2,18,17,88,56];
$limit = 2 ;

shuffle_array($array, $limit); // [2, 18, 92, 12, 17, 56, 88]
```

I expect more elements to stay in place than in the solution of Kerkouch, as some elements can have very few remaining free choices.

Comment: Although this function is rather slow when shuffling big arrays, It is reliable, also with big limits, which is not the case with Kerkouch's solution (which is great for small limits).

Answer (score 2):

I created this function to do this, but I guess it needs more improvements:

```php
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @param int $limit
 * @return array
 */
function shuffleArray(array $array, int $limit): array
{
    $arrayCount = count($array);
    $limit = min($arrayCount, $limit);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $arrayCount;) {
            $toIndex = min($arrayCount - 1, $j + rand(0, 1));
            [$array[$j], $array[$toIndex]] = [$array[$toIndex], $array[$j]];
            $j += (($toIndex === $j) ? 1 : 2);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

**Test:**

```php
$array = [92, 12, 2, 18, 17, 88, 56];
$limit = 2;
$result = shuffleArray($array, $limit); // [12, 92, 17, 2, 18, 56, 88]
```

Comment: This seems to work well. Could you perhaps explain what happens here: `[$array[$j], $array[$toIndex]] = [$array[$toIndex], $array[$j]]` ?

Comment: I swapped the values using symmetric array restructuring which was introduced in PHP7.1, otherwise, you can use a temporary variable to do that.